# How to make efficient moving index in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to know how to code an efficient index over a numpy array. For the moment, I go over the array elements using repeated additions. For example, I have to make some loops over an array A like this:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(0,100)
M = 10

for i in range(A.shape[0]-M):
    B = []
    for j in range(M):
       value = A[i+j]
       B.append(value)
```

Is there a way for me to get the values without repeatedly doing the i+j addition?

Comment: Your code as in doesn't run because you are adding `j` to `i`, but i iterates to the max index of the array.  Ie in the case when `i` is 99 and `j` is 9 the index of A you are entering is 108 which is out of the bounds for an array of length 100.

Comment: oh that's right, let me edit it

Comment: You could slice it and reduce the number of additions `B = A[i:i+M]` and drop the second loop.  It's probably about an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: How's this different from `A[-M:]` (or a similar slice)?